# Copying knockout object to another while updating the layout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When my user select one of the object in my observable array, I want to copy it to a "selectedObject". But when I do that, the layout binding on the "SelectedObject" are not updated.

So I've created an update method but I find it very difficult to maintain. is there a better way?

Here is my selected object ui:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="with: SelectedFlightObject">
    <div>select object:</div>
    <div data-bind="html: FlightNumber"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the js that I want to work but doesn't:

```
//this do not update the layout:
this.OnFlightClick = function (selectObject) {   
        this.SelectedFlightObject = selectObject;
    }.bind(this);
```

Here is the js that update the ui but find it hard to maintain.

```
UpdateFlightObject: function (currentObj, newObj) {
    currentObj.AirplaneType(newObj.AirplaneType());
    currentObj.ArrivingDate(moment(newObj.ArrivingDate()));
    currentObj.FlightNumber(newObj.FlightNumber());
    currentObj.Duration(newObj.Duration());
    currentObj.ArrivalCode(newObj.ArrivalCode());
    currentObj.DeparturCode(newObj.DeparturCode());
},


this.OnFlightClick = function (selectObject) {
    FlightFactory.UpdateFlightObject(this.SelectedFlightObject, selectObject);
}.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout requires you to use their observable wrappers.  These wrappers are where the magic happens, once bound, they are what reports changes in values and receive user input back.  Your code should look something like this.

Create:

```
this.SelectedFlightObject = ko.observable(someInitialValueOrNull);
```

Retrieve:

```
this.SelectedFlightObject();
```

Update:

```
this.SelectedFlightObject(someNewValueOrNull);
```

Comment: Yea you are right it's working. I don't know how I didn't think of this. I was so sure that this method was not working with nested observable attribute

Answer (score 0):

You should make your `SelectedFlightObject` observable so that when it changes your layout is updated.

```
this.OnFlightClick = function (selectObject) {   
    this.SelectedFlightObject(selectObject);
}.bind(this);
```

Your initial `SelectedFlightObject` would of course need to have some initial values for flight number, etc...

Remember that doing this does not create a new object